# Retornar chave primaria após inserção no MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, mysqli

Eu preciso inserir no meu banco de dados duas tabelas, uma das tabelas tem uma chave primária e a outra vai usar esse valor como chave estrangeira.

Minha dúvida é: Como consigo retornar o valor dessa chave primária logo na hora da inserção? Ou como eu posso fazer a busca da PK, sem tem o risco de eu pegar o valor de uma outra tupla que foi inserida ao mesmo tempo ou logo depois?

Obrigado

Comment: em trigger ou programação?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se tratando de MySQLi você pode utilizar a função [`insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.insert-id.php).

Exemplo da [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.insert-id.php):

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$mysqli->query("CREATE TABLE myCity LIKE City");

$query = "INSERT INTO myCity VALUES (NULL, 'Stuttgart', 'DEU', 'Stuttgart', 617000)";
$mysqli->query($query);

printf ("New Record has id %d.\n", $mysqli->insert_id);

/* drop table */
$mysqli->query("DROP TABLE myCity");

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Outra forma se tratando de mysqli, se não tiver usando uma classe (orientado a objeto), a função insert_id(); pode ser usada da seguinte forma:

```
mysqli_insert_id($conexao_com_mysql)
```

ao invés de:

```
$mysqli->insert_id
```

Esta função retorna a última chave primária inserida naquela sessão, sem  a chance de você pegar outra chave primária que não seja a que acabou de inserir.